# Amazon Pinpoint RecencyDimension Duration "At least once" not available through .Net API

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-pinpoint

I'd like to create a Pinpoint segment using a recency duration of "At least once".  This duration is available in the AWS Portal (see first screenshot), but doesn't seem to be available through the .Net SDK (see second screenshot).  Is there a way to segment by "At least once" using the SDK?  I'm writing my application in C# using the AWS .Net SDK for Pinpoint.

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to omit setting Recency filter.